# Class variable resets after the class is instantiated

Tags: c#, class, variables, constructor

So i'm writing an application that has a log in screen followed by a menu screen.

The menu has different buttons enabled for each level of user. To do this when the user logs in, an int is assigned, letting the application know what level the user is logged on and which buttons/reports to enable.

The problem I'm having is when the report is closed and the menu is called up again, the variable is reset back to the default admin level.

```
Menu M = new Menu(Permission);
M.Show();
this.Hide();
```

This code is used to pull up the menu from the log in, the int is being passed to a constructor.

```
public Menu(string Permission)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AccessLevel = int.Parse(Permission);
            LockKeys();
        }
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LockKeys();
        }
```

This is now the menu code which assigns the int to a class variable.

I've got 10 different reports and when I hit the back key on a report, this is how i call the menu back.

```
Menu shwMenu = new Menu();
shwMenu.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Now I understand the problem is that its calling the constructor that doesn't assign the variable. Right now all i can think of doing is bouncing the variable to each report and back, simply to call the correct constructor.

My question is, is there an easier way to do it ? some way to save the class variable so I don't have to re-instantiate it every time the class is called.

```
public partial class Menu : Form
    {
        private int AccessLevel;   
        public Menu(string Permission)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AccessLevel = int.Parse(Permission);
            LockKeys();
        }
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LockKeys();
        }
        private void LockKeys()
        {
            if(AccessLevel == 1)
            {
                btnSR.Enabled = false;
                btnVSC.Enabled = false;
                btnPT.Enabled = false;
                btnCT.Enabled = false;
                btnTS.Enabled = false;
                btnBookJob.Enabled = false;
                btnCompJob.Enabled = false;
                btnCompServ.Enabled = false;
                btnVS.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (AccessLevel == 2)
            {
                btnSR.Enabled = false;
                btnVSC.Enabled = false;
                btnPT.Enabled = false;
                btnCT.Enabled = false;
                btnTS.Enabled = false;
                btnBookJob.Enabled = true;
                btnCompJob.Enabled = true;
                btnCompServ.Enabled = false;
                btnVS.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (AccessLevel == 3)
            {
                btnSR.Enabled = false;
                btnVSC.Enabled = false;
                btnPT.Enabled = false;
                btnCT.Enabled = false;
                btnTS.Enabled = false;
                btnBookJob.Enabled = true;
                btnCompJob.Enabled = false;
                btnCompServ.Enabled = true;
                btnVS.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (AccessLevel == 4)
            {
                btnSR.Enabled = false;
                btnVSC.Enabled = false;
                btnPT.Enabled = false;
                btnCT.Enabled = false;
                btnTS.Enabled = true;
                btnBookJob.Enabled = false;
                btnCompJob.Enabled = false;
                btnCompServ.Enabled = false;
                btnVS.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
        private void btnVS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VehicleStatR1 VS = new VehicleStatR1();
            VS.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnSR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServRequireR3 SR = new ServRequireR3();
            SR.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnVSC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VehServCompleteR4 VSC = new VehServCompleteR4();
            VSC.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnPT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlannedTripR6 PT = new PlannedTripR6();
            PT.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ActualTripR7 CT = new ActualTripR7();
            CT.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnTS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HoursWorkedR8 TS = new HoursWorkedR8();
            TS.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnBookJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BookJobServ BJ = new BookJobServ();
            BJ.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCompJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CompJob CJ = new CompJob();
            CJ.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCompServ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CompServ CS = new CompServ();
            CS.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogIn LI = new LogIn();
            this.Hide();
            LI.Show();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

This is the menu class, the one i keep backtracking to but the AccessLevel variable changes to the default value.

Thanks

Comment: What is a "class variable"? Can you show the definition of the variable?

Comment: Just like a regular variable but one that is declared at a class level so that all methods of the class can use it.

Comment: @DamonTPelser Please post the code for it. The code presented should be a small, but complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @DamonTPelser Are you closing the main form when the report is shown?

Comment: What session state are you using ? The default (inproc) ?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Umm im just using the .hide method.

Comment: Why don't you use cookies or session state ?

Comment: @JamieR i'm doing the application using WinForms

Comment: @DamonTPelser If the form is never closed then you don't need to re-instantiate the menu, the form never dies so its internal state is never lost.

Comment: @ИвоНедев I've never used session state, ill read up on it and see if i can get it going. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Cookies are quite a nice choice if they aren't a problem for you. Ses State is very tricky as it requires you to change sessionState mode (from the Web.config) as the inproc (def. mode) is quite volatile

Comment: @DamonTPelser session state and cookies do not apply to a winforms  project.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. You have brought up some interesting topics I will read over for future assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a "static" variable which is a class level variable.

```
private static int AccessLevel;
```

Static variables are defined in a class level and all instances of the class can access them and modify them. In other words, static variables are shared between class instances. more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a static class that holds all the information you need, for example:

```
public static class CurrentUser
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static int AccessLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Which you use when your user logs in:

```
public void LogUserIn(string userName, string password)
{
    //Make sure to reset, so an invalid login doesn't retain data
    LogUserOut();

    //Do the user validation here

    CurrentUser.UserName = userName;
    CurrentUser.AccessLevel = 0; //whatever was read from your user database
}

public void LogUserOut()
{
    CurrentUser.UserName = "";
    CurrentUser.AccessLevel = int.MinValue;
}
```

And then, when you need to use the access level you don't need to worry about passing values around, for example your Menu form would look like this:

```
public partial class Menu : Form
{
    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LockKeys();
    }

    private void LockKeys()
    {
        if(CurrentUser.AccessLevel == 1)
        {
            //Enable/Disable Controls
        }
        else if (CurrentUser.AccessLevel == 2)
        {
            //Enable/Disable Controls
        }
        else if (CurrentUser.AccessLevel == 3)
        {
            //Enable/Disable Controls
        }
        else if (CurrentUser.AccessLevel == 4)
        {
            //Enable/Disable Controls
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, in order to avoid code duplication and to increase security, you should create your initialization function `LockKeys` like this:

```
    private void LockKeys()
    {
        //Set them all default false, and then only enable.
        btnSR.Enabled = false;
        btnVSC.Enabled = false;
        btnPT.Enabled = false;
        btnCT.Enabled = false;
        btnTS.Enabled = false;
        btnBookJob.Enabled = false;
        btnCompJob.Enabled = false;
        btnCompServ.Enabled = false;
        btnVS.Enabled = false;

        if(AccessLevel == 1)
        {
            btnVS.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (AccessLevel == 2)
        {
            btnBookJob.Enabled = true;
            btnCompJob.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (AccessLevel == 3)
        {
            btnBookJob.Enabled = true;
            btnCompServ.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (AccessLevel == 4)
        {
            btnTS.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```